# Use perlcassa in Window

Tags: windows, perl, cassandra, activestate

I'm trying to use perlcassa perl package in Window app. I started make but it failed because of  missing prerequisites like Thrift::XS and Tie::IxHash
Unfortunatelly such prerequisites are not available for Windows.
Any idea how to overcome this?
Or is there another Perl package for Cassandra that supports Windows?

Thanks,
Abed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cassandra command line solves the problem. It is easy, direct and no need for additional packages. i.e I wrote Cassadnra script and used -f option in Cassandra CLI to invoke it.